# Converting folder to csv file using makedirs

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the last file as a .csv file but I get a folder in the name of a string .csv

```
a = 'ICIC'
type = '.csv'
os.makedirs('D:/PMS/{}/Master/{}'.format(a, a,type))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three parameters in `format()` but only two place holders

```
os.makedirs('D:/PMS/{}/Master/{}{}'.format(a, a, type))
```

Or with f-strings if you are using Python 3

```
os.makedirs(f'D:/PMS/{a}/Master/{a}{type}')
```

Note that you can't create a file with `os.makedirs`. To do that you can use

```
folder = 'ICIC'
file_type = '.csv' # type is built-in name, don't use it as a variable
file_name = f'D:/PMS/{a}/Master/{a}{type}'

with open(file_name, 'w') as empty_csv:
    pass
```

Comment: This still creates a folder which as the string value of a .csv, so the folder created in ICIC.csv

Comment: @Mihir Updated my answer

Comment: I cant understand your code @Guy it says first create a directory then convert the a.csv folder into .csv file right?

Comment: @Mihir You can't convert folder to file. The last code snippet will create a csv file in the specified location.

Comment: I use this code        ` os.makedirs(f'D:/PMS/{a}/Master/{a}')`
                                 `file_name = f'D:/PMS/{a}/Master/{a}{type}'`
                                 `with open(file_name, 'w',encoding='utf-8') as empty_csv:
            pass`  but it also creates a folder with the name ICIC and a ICIC.csv file ,how do i delete the ICIC folder

Comment: @Mihir remove it from the path `file_name = f'D:/PMS/Master/{a}{type}'`. The path you give in `file_name` will be the file path.

Comment: Yes I tried        `os.remove(f'D:/PMS/{a}/Master/{a}')` but that gives a PermissionError

Comment: If you don't want to create the folder, don't create it. Remove it from the csv file path and don't use `os.makedirs`. Just delete the folder manually or use `os.rmdir(folder+'New Folder')` if you must do it programly. @Mihir